# Determine amount of space a serialized object transmitted in a WCF netTCP binding takes?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nettcpbinding

Is there a way to know how much space a serialized object transmitted in a WCF netTCP binding takes?
I am getting a

> The socket connection was aborted.
>   This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive
>   timeout being exceeded by the remote
>   host, or an underlying network
>   resource issue. Local socket timeout
>   was '00:00:59.9570000'

error and I think that it may be due to the size of the datatable I am transmitting back.
Is there a way in Windows debugger to determine how much space (bytes) the data to be transmitted back will take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest (and most accurate) option would probably be to set it to the max in the config (so it doesn't explode) and use WireShark to measure it during transmission; in theory you could use WCF message logging/tracing, but I've had hit-and-miss results when using that with *large* messages.

Alternatively, you could try using `NetDataContractSerializer` to write the data to a `MemoryStream`, and look at the `.Length` of the stream?

Note that if you are using *classes* (rather than `DataTable`), you might find another serializer helps; it isn't 100% scientific, but I recently compared [`NetDataContractSerialzier` and protobuf-net](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/09/protobuf-net-vs-netdatacontractserializ.html).